# Error while reading MSAccess table from Talend

Tags: ms-access, talend

Iam trying to connect to MSAccess Database using TDBConnection in Talend.Iam getting the warnings like below and later job is getting failed with Memory issue.Can any one guide me how can i go forward.

WARNING:given file does not exist --Path.

WARNING:External file --path-- does not exist.

Comment: Seems like a wrong path or the file isn't there.

Comment: But manually iam able to go to that path and able open the table.And i believe it is pointing to correct path..since it is displaying the all the objects which are delete previously. Please correct me if iam wrong .

Comment: Open? With what and how? Can you download the file?

Comment: I opened with Windows file explorer and yes i can be able to download the file.

Comment: Then the share probably isn't an SMB file share which Access requires. So, download the file to a local folder and open it from that location.